# E: Unable to locate package datacenter-gpu-manager

Tags: gpu, nvidia

I follow the dcgm installation with
https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/dcgm/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#ubuntu-lts-and-debian

But When I try
`sudo apt-get install -y datacenter-gpu-manager`
It shows
`E: Unable to locate package datacenter-gpu-manager`

My env is

```
Linux 4.15.0-167-generic #175-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 5 01:56:07 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 
. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID | sed -e 's/\.//g'
ubuntu1804
```

Answer (score 0):

I install it with the instruction in https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/dcgm/latest/user-guide/getting-started.html#ubuntu-lts-and-debian

It shows:
`E: Unable to locate package datacenter-gpu-manager`

Now I am following the instructions in https://developer.nvidia.com/dcgm#Downloads

It works.